# Is it possible to use knex returning() method with PostgreSQL to return all the rows in an operated table

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

Is it possible to return all the rows in a table after inserting one row with returning method using Knex.js. I've tried returning('*') which only returns the affected row but not all the rows in the table. I am using POSTGRESQL as my Database. Please help.

MY CODE:

```
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  const { title, content } = req.body;
 db('projects').insert({
   title: title,
   content: content,
   authorfirstname: 'John',
   authorlastname: 'Doe',
   authorid: '12345',
   createdat: new Date()
 })
 .returning('*')
 .then( project => {res.json(project)})
 .catch( err => res.status(400).json('unable to add project'))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

No. PostgreSQL doesn't support anything like that. You need to first insert and then select all rows of the table.

Comment: Maybe downvoters didn't read the question. Still in 2021 only the affected rows are returned.